# Conditional Form Field Can't Be filled

Tags: reactjs, forms, conditional-statements, react-bootstrap, react-state

When i choose and set value of status_pegawai, this form will show base on what i choose. But unfortunatelly if i fill the form, the value didn't set. I've already add bind to every function in constructor.

this is my handleField module :

```
handleField(){        
        let dasar
        switch (this.state.status_pegawai) {
            case 'PARTTIME':
                dasar= <React.Fragment><TableRow><td></td></TableRow></React.Fragment>
                this.setState({dasar})
                break;
            case 'PERBANTUAN':
                dasar= <React.Fragment>
                    <TableRow>
                        <td>No SK Penunjukan</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='text' name='no_sk_perbantuan' value={this.state.no_sk_perbantuan} onChange={this.onNoSKPerbantuanChange}></FormControl></td>
                        <td>Tanggal SK Penunjukan</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='date' name='tanggal_sk_perbantuan' value={this.state.tanggal_sk_perbantuan} onChange={this.onTanggalSKPerbantuanChange}></FormControl></td>
                    </TableRow>
                </React.Fragment>
                this.setState({dasar})
                break;
            case 'PENGAWAS':
                dasar= <React.Fragment>
                    <TableRow>
                        <td>No SK Penunjukan</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='text' name='no_sk_perbantuan' value={this.state.no_sk_perbantuan} onChange={this.onNoSKPerbantuanChange}></FormControl></td>
                        <td>Tanggal SK Penunjukan</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='date' name='tanggal_sk_perbantuan' value={this.state.tanggal_sk_perbantuan} onChange={this.onTanggalSKPerbantuanChange}></FormControl></td>
                    </TableRow>
                </React.Fragment>
                this.setState({dasar})
                break;
            case 'KONTRAK':
                dasar= <React.Fragment>
                    <TableRow>
                        <td>No SK Kontrak</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='text' name='no_sk_kontrak' value={this.state.no_sk_kontrak} onChange={this.onNoSKKontrakChange}></FormControl></td>
                        <td>Tanggal SK Kontrak</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='date' name='tanggal_sk_kontrak' value={this.state.tanggal_sk_kontrak} onChange={this.onTanggalSKKontrakChange}></FormControl></td>
                    </TableRow>
                </React.Fragment>
                this.setState({dasar})
                break;
            default:
                dasar= <React.Fragment>
                    <TableRow>
                        <td>No SK Kontrak</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='text' name='no_sk_kontrak' value={this.state.no_sk_kontrak} onChange={this.onNoSKKontrakChange}></FormControl></td>
                        <td>Tanggal SK Kontrak</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='date' name='tanggal_sk_kontrak' value={this.state.tanggal_sk_kontrak} onChange={this.onTanggalSKKontrakChange}></FormControl></td>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <td>No SK Calon Pegawai</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='text' name='no_sk_kontrak' value={this.state.no_sk_capeg} onChange={this.onNoSKCapegChange}></FormControl></td>
                        <td>Tanggal SK Calon Pegawai</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='date' name='tanggal_sk_kontrak' value={this.state.tanggal_sk_capeg} onChange={this.onTanggalSKCapegChange}></FormControl></td>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <td>No SK Pegawai Tetap</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='text' name='no_sk_kontrak' value={this.state.no_sk_kartap} onChange={this.onNoSKKartapChange}></FormControl></td>
                        <td>Tanggal SK Pegawai Tetap</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='date' name='tanggal_sk_kontrak' value={this.state.tanggal_sk_kartap} onChange={this.onTanggalSKKartapChange}></FormControl></td>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <td>No SK Masa Persiapan Pensiun</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='text' name='no_sk_kontrak' value={this.state.no_sk_mpp} onChange={this.onNoSKMPPChange}></FormControl></td>
                        <td>Tanggal SK Masa Persiapan Pensiun</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='date' name='tanggal_sk_kontrak' value={this.state.tanggal_sk_mpp} onChange={this.onTanggalSKMPPChange}></FormControl></td>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <td>No SK Pensiun</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='text' name='no_sk_pensiun' value={this.state.no_sk_pensiun} onChange={this.onNoSKPensiunChange}></FormControl></td>
                        <td>Tanggal SK Pensiun</td>
                        <td><FormControl className='formcontrol extra-large' type='date' name='tanggal_sk_pensiun' value={this.state.tanggal_sk_pensiun} onChange={this.onTanggalSKPensiunChange}></FormControl></td>
                    </TableRow>
                </React.Fragment>
                this.setState({dasar})
                break;
        }
```

and that code was called in handler function onStatusPegawaiChange

```
    async onStatusPegawaiChange(event){
        await this.setState({status_pegawai: event.target.value})
        await this.handleField()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you can't await for this.setState since it's not an async function. The workaround here is to send a callback function like so:

```js
  onStatusPegawaiChange(event){
    this.setState({ status_pegawai: event.target.value }, this.handleField);
  }
```

Since `this.handleField` function is binded you won't need for it to be called like `() => this.handleField()`

Although this may fix your problem, I would advise the following:

The `handleField` function, instead of being called to store the visual component you want to render, it should just return the component you want and be called inside the `render` function, or in this case in place of `dasar` state.

```js
handleField() {
  const { status_pegawai } = this.state;

  switch(status_pegawai) {
    case 'PARTTIME': return <React.Fragment><TableRow><td></td></TableRow></React.Fragment>;
    // ... all other cases
  }
}
```

And on the `render` function it would be something like this

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.handleField()}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

And with this, your status change function can just change to this

```js
  onStatusPegawaiChange(event){
    this.setState({ status_pegawai: event.target.value });
  }
```